# backup sql databases, folders; 7ZIP and copy to ftp

Tags: backup, sql

We are quite stuck with which solution to choose for this backup issue:

What should happen: 
First, there should be an interface were to choose several sql databases (sort of checkboxes or whatsoever), also a few folders should be backed up -> this could be part of the program or could be seperate, I think about an interface were to select folders, but a txt file (or xml) with paths-to-folders is as good.
Next, everything should be 7Zipped, SQL-DB and files seperate.
Eventually everything should be copied to a local network drive after which copied via FTP.

Also important; it could be programmed or (partly) bought but I can't be one of those expensive backup tools $1000+ etc.

I already found this fairly priced tool that does already most of the tasks

7ZIP and copy to ftp

[sqlbackupandftp.com](http://sqlbackupandftp.com/)

For your information: we had a kind of self-made tool created by a collegue (some time ago) but it became very untrustworthy and as the databases grew it couldn't handle it anymore... moving on

Please come up with suggestions. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

On my scenario i schediled a batch  script to zip one file everyday,but it didnt work as below my old script:

"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a test.rar test.txt    : this didnt work on windows 2008. but this wil work on windows 2003

i added the full path on my batch file and the below script works for me on windows 2008 server;
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a F:\ziptest\test.RAR F:\ziptest\test.txt    : this works fine

Joseph